# value of $f(2019)$ in binomial expression

Tags: binomial-coefficients

if $\displaystyle f(n)=\mathop{\sum}_{i>j\geq 0}\binom{n+1}{i}\binom{n}{j}.$ Then value of $f(2019)$ is

what i try $\displaystyle f(n)=\binom{n+1}{1}\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n+1}{2}\bigg(\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}\bigg)+\cdots  + \binom{n+1}{n+1}\bigg(\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots +\binom{n}{n}\bigg)$

How do i simplify it help me please

Comment: For this kind of question the first thing is to guess what $f(n)$ is. The way to do that is to calculate a few small values. If you work out $f(1),f(2),f(3)$, you will see that they suggest a pattern. Check it with $f(4)$.

Comment: I usually dislike people posting contest questions, which this appears to be

Comment: no it is not a contest question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\gt j}\binom{n+1}{i}\binom{n}{j}
&=\sum_{i\gt j}\left[\binom{n}{i}+\binom{n}{i-1}\right]\binom{n}{j}\tag1\\
&=\sum_{i\gt j}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}+\sum_{i\ge j}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\tag2\\
&=\sum_{i,j}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}\tag3\\[6pt]
&=2^n\cdot2^n\tag4\\[15pt]
&=4^n\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: [Pascal's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule)
$(2)$: substitute $i\mapsto i+1$ in the right-hand sum
$(3)$: swap $i$ and $j$ by symmetry in the right-hand sum
$(4)$: $\sum\binom{n}{i}=(1+1)^n=2^n$
$(5)$: simplify

Comment: I think that $\sum_{i\gt j}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}+\sum_{i\ge j}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}=\sum_{i,j}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}$ needs a little explanation, like $\sum_{i\ge j}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j} = \sum_{j\ge i}\binom{n}{i}\binom{n}{j}$.

Comment: @WolfgangKais: I have added explanation

Answer (score 2):

Let's first calculate $2f(n)$:

$$
\begin{align}
2f(n) &= \sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{i=j+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{i}\binom{n}{j} + \sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{i=j+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{i}\binom{n}{n-j}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{i=j+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{i} + \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{n-j}\sum_{i=j+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{i}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{i=j+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{i} + \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{i=n-j+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{i}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{i=j+1}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{i} + \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom{n+1}{i}\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{i}\\
&= 2^n2^{n+1} = 2^{2n+1}
\end{align}
$$

Therefore: $f(n) = 2^{2n} = 4^n$ and thus $f(2019) = 4^{2019}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First show that $\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}=2^n$.